# How to multiply a lot of matrices without a loop?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have a numpy array of matricies

```py
X = np.array([[[1.1, 2.1],
               [2.1, 1.1]],

              [[1.2, 2.2],
               [2.2, 1.2]],

              [[1.3, 2.3],
               [2.3, 1.3]]])
```

How do I make a matrix multiplication of all of them?

The problem comes from the function `X = foo(a)` that gives a matrix output. Once I calculate it on vector of length `N`, I have `N` matricies. Mathematically, I want to find this

```py
ans = X[0] @ X[1] ... @ X[N-1]
```

For extremely large `N` loop approach is going to be slow :(
So I want to vectorize it somehow.

Any help is appriciated!

Comment: This doesn't 'vectorize' because there isn't compiled code that does sequential `dot`.  `matmul` does parellel batched `dots`

Answer (score 3):

[numpy.linalg.multi_dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html) helps to multiply a sequence of matrices at once, and also internally optimizes the call order in order to reduce the number of computations required.

I also observe that there's a mathematical pattern in the sequence of matrices provided in question. If you could reduce it to a formula, then perhaps you could reduce the number of matrices needed to multiply.

Comment: But these arrays are all the same shape.  Order does not matter.  I don't think multidot will help.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah I see, yes you are right. I just found out that multidot doesn't run any C code, it just calls np.dot internally after optimizing the order. Still, it should not be slower than a manual loop I think?

Comment: I looked at it in 2017, see Ofek's link.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, just typing np.linalg.multi_dot(X) works as expected.